# error with input chat (css)

Tags: css

I have a chat item in my site but for some reason, when I input chat, it runs of the page (width to infinity) rather than breaking a new line. Ideally, the chat should stop where the time is displayed and break into a new line there. How can I fix this? thank you!

```
.chat-add {
position: relative;
top: 0px;
margin: 10px;
}

.chat-add > input[type="text"] {
padding: 0 65px 0 10px !important;
}

.chat-container {
position: absolute;
float: right;
width: 300px;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;
}

.chat {
position: absolute;
bottom: 320px;
top: 57px;
margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}

.chat-output {
position: relative;
padding: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
overflow: auto;
background-color: white;
height: 100%;
/* background: url(../images/chat-background.png) no-repeat; */
/* border: 2px solid #3B5998; */
/* border-radius: 5px; */
/* -moz-border-radius: 5px;*/
/* -webkit-border-radius: 5px; */
}

.chat-message {
position: relative;
display: table;
float: left;
margin-bottom: 4px;
width: 100%;
border-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) !important;
}



.chat-user-message {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 220px;
min-height: 16px;
padding: 4px;
margin-left: 32px;
font: 12px sans-serif;
display: table-cell;
}

.chat-time {
font-size: 10px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
width: 45px;
text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: You say its a problem with javascript, but the code is css?

Comment: Sorry, you were right! My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use CSS3, you can use the word-wrap property.  This would probably be extremely helpful, as it describes the problem you are indicating as well as the solution:  http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_text_effects.asp

Another that may be helpful is this which works in pre-CSS3:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_pos_overflow_auto

and this

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp